# Managing maximum delivery attempts and rate limiting separately with Google Cloud Pub/Sub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am utilizing the Maximum Delivery Attempts feature provided by Google Cloud Pub/Sub. This feature allows messages to be sent to a dead-letter topic after five failed delivery attempts, which is beneficial for manual message handling in case of failures.

However, we are also implementing an artificial rate limit on our Functions by setting Max-instances=2. The objective is to constantly have two functions pinging the API at maximum capacity.

```
Maximum delivery attempts: 5
Max instances : 2
```

My expectation was that the dead-letter topic would only receive failed messages. Unfortunately, it is also receiving messages that couldn't be delivered on time, resulting in a 429 error: "The request was aborted because there was no available instance." These messages might be retried multiple times, potentially 20, 30, or even 40 times, depending on the busy state of the instance.

Setting the Maximum Delivery Attempts to 40 is not ideal since it would mean retrying a failure 40 times.

Is there a way to handle failures and limiting separately?

Thank you!

--
Béranger

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the error handling for PubSub Push messages.
Every answer to the request from PubSub to your service whichs is not 1xx/2xx (see https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push?hl=en#receive_push) will be handled as a failure which leads to a retry.

Do you need to rate limit your own service or do you need to rate limit because of another service you call yourself?

If it is the latter, you can implement the rate limiting in your services. There are plenty libraries for this.

Otherwise you could implement rate limiting by acknowledging the out-of-rate messages immediately without processing them - and then your service just publishes the same message back to the source topic.

Edit: I assume that you somehow know if you reached your limit or not. If this is the case, you check on each incoming message if you may call the external API or not. If so, you process the message. If you reached your limit, you either just return 2xx without furter processing (= discarding the message) or you publish the same message again and then return 2xx ( = manually replaying / retrying) the message. this way, "valid" messages do not hit the retry limit as you produce new messages (with the same content)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An other service I call myself has a rate limit. For now we have x max-instances of Cloud Functions and a Pub/Sub topic retrying if no instance available. Can you explain how to "acknowledging the out-of-rate messages immediately without processing them"?

Comment: I assume that you somehow know if you reached your limit or not. If this is the case, you check on each incoming message if you may call the external API or not. If so, you process the message. If you reached your limit, you either just return 2xx without furter processing (= discarding the message) or you publish the same message again and then return 2xx ( = manually replaying  / retrying) the message. this way, "valid" messages do not hit the retry limit as you produce new messages (with the same content)

Comment: Or you could just switch to Pull

Comment: @Béranger so, did you manage to make it work?